# How to use segment feature in explorer reports within the google analytics api , can support for segments be provided within api?

Tags: google-sheets, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

How to use segment feature in explorer reports within the google analytics api , can support for segments be provided within api??

As a CRO Agency we rely heavily on building segments to analyze user behaviour and calc conversion rates, using filters is resulting in ommitance of couting conversions within the same session as GA4 is event based , can segment feature be added to api ASAP !! or is there any alternate solution for this ????

Using explorer reports to extract and dump data to google sheets but that is a very manual and laborius tasks, previously built custom reports using GA-UA api and spreadsheet add on.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.